# 3d Primitives not Rendering correctly when createGraphics is used in p5js and WEBGL

Tags: rendering, webgl, p5.js

I am trying to write some code that draws a rotating cube on an offscreen graphics window in p5js using WebGL. when I draw the cube directly on the canvas it works fine, but when I try and draw it on the graphics object, it renders incorrectly.

```
    let canvas2;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  canvas2 = createGraphics(400,400,WEBGL)
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  canvas2.background(255);
  canvas2.push();

  canvas2.noFill();
  canvas2.rotateX(0.01*frameCount);
  canvas2.box(50,50,50);
  
  
  image(canvas2,0,0,400,400);
  canvas2.pop();
}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the main canvas, `p5.Graphics` objects do not have their [depth buffer](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Depth-testing) automatically cleared for each frame. You can do this manually by calling [WebGLRenderingContext.clearDepth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/clearDepth) on the `drawingContext` for your `p5.Graphics` or you can just use the built in p5.js `clear()` function which will clear the depth buffer and the colors.

```js
let canvas2;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  canvas2 = createGraphics(400, 400, WEBGL);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  
  // This line fixes the issue:
  canvas2.clear();
  
  canvas2.background(255);
  canvas2.push();

  canvas2.noFill();
  canvas2.rotateX(0.01 * frameCount);
  canvas2.box(50, 50, 50);

  image(canvas2, 0, 0, 400, 400);
  canvas2.pop();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```